# Event Sourcing and when to perform validation

Tags: .net-core, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm in the process of learning about Event Sourcing and CQRS in distributed systems and I'm having some trouble trying to work out when is the best time to perform validation ... before, or after, the event has been stored?  I've done a heap of searching and reading on the subject but I just can't seem to find an answer/suggestion that addresses this question.

For example (simple example), if I have a Web API request to withdraw some money from a bank account, I might perform the following validation:

1. Does the bank account exist?
2. Does the bank account have enough funds to withdraw?

When the request comes in, do I save the event before performing the above validation (and risk storing invalid events) or after the validation (and risk something going wrong part-way through the process, like the service going down, and not storing the event at all)?  In the case of CQRS, is the event stored before the Command is executed or as part of the Command (in the Command handler)?

I can appreciate some validation would be performed before even making the request (e.g. valid amount to withdraw) but there might be a situation where some validation can't be done before making the request.

This also leads to working out how I can return an error (e.g. Bank Account is not valid) in the response of the Web API call?

My understanding of this subject may be all wrong, but as I mentioned before, I'm just learning this subject and I'm hoping someone either has an answer, or can point me to some posts/articles, that will help my understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Eventuous docs](https://eventuous.dev/docs/application/app-layer/):

In general, the command handling flow can be described like this:

1. The edge receives a command via its API (HTTP, gRPC, SignalR, messaging, etc).
2. It passes the command over to the application service. As the edge is responsible for authentication and some authorisation, it can enrich commands with user credentials.
3. The command service, which is agnostic to the API itself, handles the command and gives a response to the edge (positive or negative).
4. The API layer then returns the response to the calling party.

The command service itself performs the following operations when handling one command:

1. Extract the aggregate id from the command, if necessary.
2. Instantiate all the necessary value objects. This could effectively reject the command if value objects cannot be constructed. The command service could also load some other aggregates, or any other information, which is needed to execute the command but won’t change state.
3. If the command expects to operate on an existing aggregate instance, this instance gets loaded from the Aggregate Store.
4. Execute an operation on the loaded (or new) aggregate, using values from the command, and the constructed value objects.
5. The aggregate either performs the operation and changes its state by producing new events, or rejects the operation.
6. If the operation was successful, the service persists new events to the store. Otherwise, it returns a failure to the edge.

I would also separate the domain model invariants and validations. I use the word "validation" when I check if a provided string value is indeed a bank account number, a valid phone number, mandatory fields, etc. Domain invariants, including aggregate invariants (can the withdrawal be processed) and cross-aggregate invariants (one customer cannot have more than ten bank accounts, can't imagine anything else really).

If a given account doesn't exist, loading the aggregate for it would simply fail. The aggregate itself, however, can answer questions like:

- Can a given user withdraw funds from this account
- Is the account active, not blocked
- Is the withdrawal amount within allowed withdrawal limits for the time period

Just a note from experience - banks rarely care if you have money on the account when you create a payment. It only matters when the payment gets executed, which almost never happen in real time.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey-Zimarev for your response.  This is a great explanation.  So if I understand you correctly, the Command handles the validation, loading the aggregate, etc ... and if all that is successful, only then is the event recorded in the Event Store?  Otherwise, the command fails (e.g. account doesn't exist) and returns the response to the caller (edge)?

Comment: Events represent state transitions. It means that your domain model decided that the action can be executed and everything is correct. So, yes, you described it correctly. Command handling can fail, for example, when you construct value objects, and a value object logic says "I cannot be constructed from given arguments". Like, an email value object checks the given argument, if it is a valid email address. Aggregates protect their own invariants to ensure that their state is valid. Otherwise, the action cannot be performed and the command will fail.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the useful way to approach things is to define an event as something for which processing cannot fail (you can process an event by ignoring it, but it shouldn't ever fail).  Commands, on the other hand, can fail, or result in zero or more events.

Accordingly, there's no validation of events, only of commands.  In the bank account example, you could have a withdrawal command where there's insufficient funds available be rejected, or it could result in the withdrawal event and an overdraft event (e.g. if the amount of the resulting overdraft is within policy).

One component's (I'm deliberately trying to avoid using the word "service") event can be another component's command.

It is, by the way, completely valid to persist objects whose processing can fail, but that's a technique related to event sourcing called command sourcing; command sourcing and event sourcing can often be usefully combined, especially if the commands are some other component's events.

Comment: +1   Just mentioning there is a camp out there that think commands shouldn't fail, just generate different events. But there's lot of thoughts and no one right way to implement commands and events.

Comment: @levi-ramsey ... I like your explanation and it is helping me formulate a rough 'guideline' I can use.  Using my bank example, if I tried to withdraw from an account that didn't exist, the request would come into the command, the command validation would fail, and no event would be generated/stored.  However, if the account did exist, the command would pass validation and generate/store a withdraw event (assuming other validation passed) ... therefore only recording events that never fail.

Comment: +1 for this. One thing I am interpreting is written between the lines from @levi-ramsey comment about "command sourcing" is commands are first-class citizens. When a command is issued to an API, several irrefutable events can occur such as `CommandStarted`, `CommandFailed` and `CommandSucceeded`.

@levi-ramsey I am interested to hear more why you avoid using the word "service"

Comment: I avoid it because it's tied up in a lot of readers' minds as being specific to one style of component of a system (e.g. a microservice (in which a lot gets read into the "micro"), or various frameworks which have their own definition of a "service").  There's a world of ways to implement components (e.g. as streaming jobs in Flink/Spark (though I also use the term "jorvice" for always-running streaming jobs, it's not common usage) and having a very specific definition of what a service entails can constrain to sub-optimal choices.

Answer (score 1):

Events are statements of fact and cannot be changed.  They represent something that actually happened.

You could introduce validation on a command before it results in a series of events.

Since you mentioned a bank account, many times a bank will not restrict you from overdrawing your account. They just add a new fact  that represents an overdraft fee as a result of the withdrawal.  This scenario involves a reaction to a withdrawal event, not validation before the event occurs.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I might perform validation on the command (e.g. does the bank account exist) before generating, and storing, any event(s)?  Meaning that if the bank account didn't exist, the command would return an error and therefore not generate/store any events?

Comment: There's no one way to do it. You could generate a new event indicating an invalid bank account or you could return an error.